# What is the difference between using spark udf and using map with rdd?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Wanted to know whether there is any performance difference between using Spark UDF vs using the same function in map with RDD?

Example:

```
def square(a):
  return a*a

spark_udf = udf(square, IntegerType())
df = df.withColumn('square_of_number', udf(col('number')))
```

vs

```
df = df.rdd.map(lambda x: square(x)).toDF()
```

Just want to understand how differently are the above two statements executed in Spark.

Thank you.

Comment: Would love to know te question to this answer as well